# Should I use open engine oil that was left over from previous oil change

Tags: engine, oil-change, lubrication

So, I have accumulated 4 Liter engine oil which are left overs of previous oil changes. I have accumulated these amount in 1 year. So should I use it or not? I use Mobil 1 full synthetic 0w 40.

Please give me suggestions.

Comment: If you can, check for the expiration date of the earliest leftover oil container. I generally use the leftover oil for the very next oil change instead of accumulating it.

Comment: You may have heard warnings about using opened, old brake fluid.  Oil is fine, but brake fluid readily absorbs moisture, so there's usually warnings about only using a "new, unopened" bottle of fluid.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If the oil is unused, and unopened, there is nothing wrong with using it.

> [ExxonMobil](https://mobiloil.com/en/faq/ask-our-auto-experts/questions-for-auto-experts/shelf-life-of-unopened-mobil-1-quarts) recommends a five-year maximum shelf life for engine oils,
>   including Mobil 1™ synthetic motor oil.

Opened oil can vary in shelf life due to extreme temperature, humidity and other conditions like dusty environments. These things will shorten the life.

Comment: thanks for the comment. Considering the opened engine oil have been in normal temperature, low humidity and dust free environment, then do you think it can last one year in shelf?

Comment: In those conditions, my opinion would be, yes.

Comment: How does a dusty environment affect shelf life if its stored in a sealed can?

Comment: @MarkW It would probably depend on how well the can is sealed and how dusty the environment. Hard to say for sure.

Answer (score 10):

Yes, as Charlie says, as long as it has been stored correctly it should be fine. I generally use the leftovers from one change when I do the next so that it's not sitting around for too long - e.g. if I need 4L and I have 5L cans, I'll have 1L left, so next time I'll use that 1L, plus 3L from the next can.

Answer (score 5):

A bit of a late answer here, but I would agree with the answers already posted: Yes, you can definitely use it.  That being said, I would not recommend storing engine oil for more than a few years, since the additives in the oil can begin to settle out of the oil.

Store it, as already said, in a dry location with fairly stable temperature and humidity, but don't hold on to it for 5-10 years: engine oil does eventually break down.

Comment: Settle out?  Would they not get thoroughly mixed while the engine runs?

Comment: @donjuedo -- it settles out _to the bottom_.  If every single drop from the can could be scraped into the engine, then yes, it could be mixed in the engine.  In reality, though, the oil at the bottom will tend to be left in the can, and that residue would have the lion's share of the additives.

Comment: I always shake oil before using it to avoid this. Who knows how long its sat in a warehouse/shop/dealer.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can, and you might decant it into smaller containers for top ups on the road. In summer you do not want too much air as considerable vapour pressure can build up. It is common on farms and anywhere plant is maintained to buy in drums. It is too expensive to waste.